# Install multiple versions of Python via Homebrew

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, homebrew, pyenv

There is a way to install older versions of Python using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and mantain installed the latest Python version? I know that [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) is the simplest answer to my question ([pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) also), but I really don't like the way it manages the files. I would like to have multiple installations in `/usr/local/Cellar` in order to access them via `virtualenv` and create envs with a specific Python version.

Comment: Yes, you can install multiple versions of the same formula, and just pass the relevant executable's path as `-p`

Comment: Homebrew doesn't have that kind of support for Python. It only provides python for python 2.7.12 and python3 for the latest version of Python 3. Having tapped homebrew/versions doesn't provides the older versions of Python.

Comment: `homebrew/versions` doesn't, but it's the same functionality and e.g. [`derekkwok/python`](https://derekkwok.net/blog/6/installing-older-versions-of-python-with-brew/) provides the recipes.

Comment: There are others recipes with more versions? Like 2.7.9 or so..!

Comment: This question does not have an answer. Here is one. You can accomplish this using third party recipes, like the ones at https://github.com/danpalmer/homebrew-python, danpalmer's fork of zoidbergwill's formulas. Third party recipes are pretty much the way to go here, the main drawback being that they are sporadically maintained and tend to disappear, like the derekkwok/python link above. (And yeah, no, the "duplicate" question is not a duplicate, and its answers do not address this question.) :) So it goes.